# Editor Template to add existing objects to list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I want to make an Editor Template that let's me choose an item from a list of options, and that item gets added to the list in a certain way.  In other words I'll reference the Editor Template like (where References is a list of items):

```
@EditorFor(m => m.References)
```

And the output will look like:
(anchor for each item in the list)

```
<a href="whatever1">Reference1</a>
<a href="whatever2">Reference2</a>
<a href="whatever3">Reference3</a>
```

and then a jquery autocomplete input field with a select function that adds to this list (or something equivalent)

```
<input type='text' class='autocomplete-references' />
```

How can I accomplish this?  I can't seem to figure out how to even start to do this.

Comment: I don't think you really understand how EditorTemplates work, or what they are used for.. You don't use EditorTemplates to "let you choose an item from a list of options".  Instad, you use an EditorTemplate to render an item in a list.  You would typically wrap EditorTemplates in code to let you do your item selection.  You might put that in a Partial, for instance..  EditorTemplates work best when you can render a discrete item of a specific type.. even if it's made up of subtypes.  For instance, you can use an EditorTemplate to render a collection, but you should wrap that in something else.

Comment: Why wouldn't I use an EditorTemplate to render the editing function of a member of one of my models?  Why would I make an EditorTemplate to render an item in a list?  Isn't that a DisplayTemplate?

Comment: You misunderstand.. you don't render the editing functionality.  You render the ITEM to be edited.  If this functionality is a simple textbox, or checkbox, then fine... but if it's an involved selection process, then you are doing it in the wrong place.  As an example, you can use editor templates to render the individual rows of a grid, but you don't use it to render the grid itself. or functionality like paging or sorting.

Comment: I think you're missing me here.  I'm not trying to put a controller action inside my view, just display an editable list of items that is backed by a model.  In my view I would like to type `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyList)`.  The items themselves are not the issue, and I do not want the individual items to be editable, they are predefined.  It is the selection of the items that matters.

Comment: I may be missing you, but that's because you're not really explaining yourself well.  EditorFor is used for rendering items based on type.  It is not used for rendering selection mechanisms.  That is something you want to provide outside of your Editor.. because EditorTemplates iterate over collections, it would create duplicate logic, one for each item.  You typically want a single overriding selection mechanism for all items.  You can think of an EditorTemplate as being similar to an older ASP.NET Repeater control.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.EditorFor` uses what's called "editor templates". There's some default ones built into MVC to handle a few basic scenarios, but you can add your own by creating views in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates`, named after either a type (DateTime.cshtml, Boolean.cshtml, String.cshtml, etc.), one of the members of the `DataType` enum (EmailAddress.cshtml, ImageUrl.cshtml, etc.), or anything you want (with caveats).

The "anything you want" part requires that you then either decorate your property with `UIHint`, where you'll tell it what template to use, or specify the template explicitly. For example, if you added `[UIHint("Foo")]` to a property, `Html.EditorFor` would look for the editor template, `Foo.cshtml`. Alternatively, you can pass the template name to `Html.EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty, "Foo")
```

The reason this part is important is because you can't actually have an editor template for something like `IEnumerable<Reference>`. In order to use a custom editor template with something like your `References` property, you would have to do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.References, "MyReferencesEditorTemplate")
```

Or, use `UIHint` on the property as described above.